# Recent and interesting application of infinite series or inifite sequence in the optimization theory or any other area

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, operations-research

I'm looking for an interesting application of Sequences and Series (theory from mathematical analysis) in the field of Operational Research, in particular involving combinatorics or linear optimization problems.

I have tried only chat GPT for now and all I could get is an application of Dynamic programming to solve the knapsack problem where series and sequences are defined for recurrence.

I was wondering if there is another one or maybe an interesting application not from the Operation Research fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for OR applications where finding the limit of an infinite series, or a point around which an infinite series (or sub-series) clusters, is crucial, or are you just looking for applications that generate a finite number of points in a sequence, with the last one likely the answer? (Dynamic programming for a knapsack problem would fall into the latter category.)

Comment: The fist one,  OR applications where finding the limit of an infinite series.